# Angular - How to check if file exists without fs

Tags: typescript, fs, angular7

As `fs` [seems not to work anymore since Angular 6](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681)
I haven't found an alternative way to check if a file exists.
In my special case I have to check if a specific image file exists in the assets folder, e.g. something like this:

```
if (fileExists('path')) { doSomething(); }
```

I've tried to install the [file-exists package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-exists) but this uses

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
```

which apparently is not supported by Angular 7.

Is there anybody who can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you could probably make a GET request to the file?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you, scipper. Yes, that's the way I manage it now. But I hoped there would be a easier, one-line function to check this.

Here the code (it returns the folder, not the file, so I can use it fore more purposes):

```
getFolder(subFolder: string): Observable<string> {
    const folderPath = `assets/folder/${subFolder.toLocaleUpperCase()}`;
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${folderPath}/file.png`, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' })
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          return folderPath;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
          return of('assets/folder/default');
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a snippet that returns a boolean Observable for whether or not a file exists at a given URL:

```
fileExists(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.get(url)
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
                return true;
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                return of(false);
            })
        );
}
```

Or, the same thing but in a more concise, one-line format:

```
public fileExists(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.get(url).pipe(map(() => true), catchError(() => of(false)));
}
```

Comment: this will always return false, as it will always throw an error because it expects a json response, but receives a binary data

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers didn't work for you (like myself) then try this. If the image doesn't exist it simply returns the default image path.

```
fileExists(id: number) {
    const folderPath = `../../assets/images/${id}.jpg`;

    this._http.get(folderPath, { responseType: 'text' }).toPromise().then(response => {
      this.imagePath = folderPath;
    }).catch(error => {
      return this.imagePath;
    });
}
```

Then in the html: `<img class="" src="{{imagePath}}" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FileService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fileExists(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        const success: boolean = err.status.toString().startsWith('2')
        return of(success)
      })
    )
  }
}
```